# Why are these <li> tags different widths between WebKit and everything else?

Tags: css

Why are the `li` elements in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/xgxkv/2/) 30 pixels tall in WebKit browsers (the desired height), and 41 pixels tall in Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only set line-height.  Try also setting the height of the li.

```
.container ul li {
    border: 1px solid #888;
    margin: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    height:30px;  //added this
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/aaronj1335/xgxkv/4

Answer (score 4):

Because you haven't done any kind of reset in your CSS.

Every browser has different default settings in the visual representation of HTML elements. For this reason it is very useful to implement a CSS reset that removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default browser styling settings.

Comment: Not a fan of stock resets. Big fan of resetting particular elements that need it, though (lists and list components being one of the more important ones). :-) I wouldn't say this is a 'must-do' for all sites.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a proper `line-height` to the span child solves the problem.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xgxkv/8/

Comment: I don't think this does solve it -- it looks like the line is off center in FF.